GridDB Functions in Python
I have encountered some issues while integrating DB with authentication systems with the API functions provided by GridDB. They seem to be incorrect. Could you please advise if there are equivalent functions available in the GridDB API? I would appreciate guidance on this matter.
Below are my codes
# Example: Configuring LDAP authentication for GridDB
gridstore.set_authentication_mode(griddb.AuthMode.CLIENT)
gridstore.set_authentication_username("user")
gridstore.set_authentication_password("password")
gridstore.set_authentication_provider("ldap")


The python client does not contain any sort of authentication functions. you can see the API here: https://griddb.org/python_client/PythonAPIReference.htm
The python client though is a bit pared down compared to the Java API, but even that API doesn't have any authentication features: https://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v5_4/GridDB_Java_API_Reference.html
